# Getting error of php version in Laravel 6 composer update even though my php version is 7.2.1

Tags: php, mamp, php-7.2, laravel-6

I downloaded a laravel 6 demo project and setting it up in my mac mamp. Initialy my php version was 7.1.23 and i was getting this error.

```
Warning: require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel_demo/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel_demo/public/index.php on line 26

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel_demo/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel_demo/public/index.php on line 26
```

So i changed my php version to 7.2.1 by renaming old php version folder in mamp. Now if i run `phpinfo()` It is showing php version 7.2.1. But when i run `composer update` in terminal i am getting this error.

```
Problem 1
- This package requires php ^7.2 but your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- laravel/framework v6.4.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.3.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.0.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework 6.x-dev requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0].
```

Is this issue related to laravel setup or my php version or am i missing something in updating my php version?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 6 requires PHP >= 7.2.0 and your version is 7.1.23.

What happening in this case?

If you run `phpinfo()` by a file accessed on your browser via http server. The output maybe different for your terminal. If the PHP enabled on your HTTP server (like apache or nginx) is the newest (7.2) maybe is the case to check the version in your terminal running `php -v`.

In some cases the php are updated to http server but, the "cli" version are not updated and points to older version, it depends on the way that the system are updated.

If this situation is your case, you need to check if `php-cli` are correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks i resolved it by changing php version in bash-profile

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6 is required PHP Version is PHP >= 7.2.0.
your version is 7.1.23 that is lower requirement.

you install mamp 7.2 or latest versions.

Comment: But when i am running phpinfo(). It is showing php version 7.2.1

Comment: @VinitSingh Then it's likely your CLI and your webserver have different PHP versions.